# Are chiropractors the only professionals who will "adjust" the spine?

Tags: spine, musculoskeletal-system, chiropractor, ebm-evidence-based-med

I've had various periods of extended back pain that chiropractors can relieve by "adjusting" (a.k.a. "cracking") my spine in just a moment, providing immediate and long-term relief from pain sometimes in a single visit.

I've asked massage therapists if they can do that, and they decline.

When I see an MD for the exact same problem they may prescribe anti-inflammatories and seem more concerned with whether it's worth sending me to get an MRI, or whether I should just "give it time."

Are there any other professionals that will do the spinal adjustments for which chiropractors are known?  If not, why?

Comment: `providing immediate and permanent relief from pain` -- It doesn't sound very permanent if it keeps recurring.

Comment: @CareyGregory - The only truly permanent relief from pain is death.  If I've had the same back pain for weeks, and then after "relief" I go months or years without that pain, I consider that a "permanent" fix.  The fact that my back (and, indeed, my whole body) is still susceptible to injury does not mean that a particular injury was not healed.

Comment: I'd suggest calling it "long-term" since permanent doesn't mean months or years; it means forever. Not a criticism, just a suggestion.

Comment: @CareyGregory - OK, made that change.  But it might be important for me to clarify: "Back pain" is a very broad symptom, and "the back" is a very large and complex system.  I've seen chiropractors for "back pain" three times in my life.  I don't have evidence that in each case it was the same pathology causing the pain.  If each time they said something like, "Oh, your L4 vertebrae is out of line," then I might suggest it was a *recurring* injury.  But I don't remember any such details.